# OpenSSL rust failed compilation

Tags: rust, openssl

I'm new to rust and I'm trying to compile a rust code with the command : `cargo build --all --target wasm32-unknown-unknown --release`.

However I get this error message :

```
error: failed to run custom build command for `openssl-sys v0.9.75`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `PATHTORUSTPROJECT/target/release/build/openssl-sys-65a5f06c10f48aeb/build-script-main` (exit status: 101)
  --- stdout
  cargo:rustc-cfg=const_fn
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=WASM32_UNKNOWN_UNKNOWN_OPENSSL_NO_VENDOR
  WASM32_UNKNOWN_UNKNOWN_OPENSSL_NO_VENDOR unset
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=OPENSSL_NO_VENDOR
  OPENSSL_NO_VENDOR unset
  CC_wasm32-unknown-unknown = None
  CC_wasm32_unknown_unknown = None
  TARGET_CC = None
  CC = None
  CFLAGS_wasm32-unknown-unknown = None
  CFLAGS_wasm32_unknown_unknown = None
  TARGET_CFLAGS = None
  CFLAGS = None
  CRATE_CC_NO_DEFAULTS = None
  DEBUG = Some("false")
  running "perl" "./Configure" "--prefix=PATHTORUSTPROJECT/target/wasm32-unknown-unknown/release/build/openssl-sys-4189d728cdf3ef76/out/openssl-build/install" "--openssldir=/usr/local/ssl" "no-dso" "no-shared" "no-ssl3" "no-unit-test" "no-comp" "no-zlib" "no-zlib-dynamic" "no-md2" "no-rc5" "no-weak-ssl-ciphers" "no-camellia" "no-idea" "no-seed" "gcc" "-O2" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "--target=wasm32-unknown-unknown"
  Configuring OpenSSL version 1.1.1q (0x1010111fL) for gcc
  Using os-specific seed configuration
  Creating configdata.pm
  Creating Makefile

  The library could not be configured for supporting multi-threaded
  applications as the compiler options required on this system are not known.
  See file INSTALL for details if you need multi-threading.

  **********************************************************************
  ***                                                                ***
  ***   OpenSSL has been successfully configured                     ***
  ***                                                                ***
  ***   If you encounter a problem while building, please open an    ***
  ***   issue on GitHub <https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues>  ***
  ***   and include the output from the following command:           ***
  ***                                                                ***
  ***       perl configdata.pm --dump                                ***
  ***                                                                ***
  ***   (If you are new to OpenSSL, you might want to consult the    ***
  ***   'Troubleshooting' section in the INSTALL file first)         ***
  ***                                                                ***
  **********************************************************************
  running "make" "depend"
  running "make" "build_libs"
  perl "-I." -Mconfigdata "util/dofile.pl" \
            "-oMakefile" include/crypto/bn_conf.h.in > include/crypto/bn_conf.h
  perl "-I." -Mconfigdata "util/dofile.pl" \
            "-oMakefile" include/crypto/dso_conf.h.in > include/crypto/dso_conf.h
  perl "-I." -Mconfigdata "util/dofile.pl" \
            "-oMakefile" include/openssl/opensslconf.h.in > include/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make depend && /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make _build_libs
  
  clang  -I. -Iinclude  -O3 -O2 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fPIC --target=wasm32-unknown-unknown -DOPENSSLDIR="\"/usr/local/ssl\"" -DENGINESDIR="\"PATHTORUSTPROJECT/target/wasm32-unknown-unknown/release/build/openssl-sys-4189d728cdf3ef76/out/openssl-build/install/lib/engines-1.1\"" -DNDEBUG  -MMD -MF crypto/aes/aes_cfb.d.tmp -MT crypto/aes/aes_cfb.o -c -o crypto/aes/aes_cfb.o crypto/aes/aes_cfb.c

  --- stderr
  apps/bf_prefix.c:10:10:apps/s_socket.c:11:10:  apps/s_cb.c:11:10: fatal error: fatal error: fatal error: 'stdio.h' file not found'stdio.h' file not found

  #include <stdio.h>
           ^~~~~~~~~
  'stdio.h' file not found
  #include <stdio.h>
           ^~~~~~~~~
  #include <stdio.h>
           ^~~~~~~~~
  apps/apps.c:18:10: fatal error: 'stdio.h' file not found
  #include <stdio.h>
           ^~~~~~~~~
  In file included from apps/app_rand.c:10:
  In file included from apps/apps.h:13:
  In file included from ./e_os.h:16:
  In file included from include/openssl/e_os2.h:243:
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/13.1.6/include/inttypes.h:21:15: fatal error: 'inttypes.h' file not found
  #include_next <inttypes.h>
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~
  In file included from apps/opt.c:9:
  In file included from apps/apps.h:13:
  In file included from ./e_os.h:16:
  In file included from include/openssl/e_os2.h:243:
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/13.1.6/include/inttypes.h:21:15: fatal error: 'inttypes.h' file not found
  #include_next <inttypes.h>
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~
  error: unable to create target: 'No available targets are compatible with triple "wasm32-unknown-unknown"'
  error: unable to create target: 'No available targets are compatible with triple "wasm32-unknown-unknown"'
  1 error generated.
  1 error generated.
  make[1]: *** [crypto/aes/aes_cfb.o] Error 1
  make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
  make: *** [build_libs] Error 2
  thread 'main' panicked at '


  Error building OpenSSL:
      Command: "make" "build_libs"
      Exit status: exit status: 2


      ', /Users/myuser/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/openssl-src-111.22.0+1.1.1q/src/lib.rs:490:13
error Command failed with exit code 101.
```

I want to use the openSSL dependancy to verify a RSA signature.

I have already tried xcode-select --installation as suggested in other posts. But this doesn't seem to change anything. I also tried to reinstall it.

I'm using macOs Monterey (12.4) with M1 chip.

Any idea how to fix it ?

Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rust web assembly fails to build with openssl error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62493291/rust-web-assembly-fails-to-build-with-openssl-error)

Comment: TLDR the duplicate: [OpenSSL doesn't support WebAssembly](https://github.com/rustwasm/wasm-bindgen/issues/1529#issuecomment-491824571).

Comment: Maybe you can replace OpenSSL with [`rustls`](https://github.com/rustls/rustls)?

Comment: @frankenapps [_Rustls uses ring for implementing the cryptography in TLS. As a result, rustls only runs on platforms supported by ring. At the time of writing this means x86, x86-64, armv7, and aarch64._](https://github.com/rustls/rustls#platform-support), so a priori no wasm.